# Find length of 3d curve defined by data points in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, curve

I have a dataset (numpy array) `points` of shape (3,N) containing some 3D points that form a curve. I use the following code to get the plot below:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(*points)
plt.show()
```

[image: curve generated by points]

How do I find the total length of the curve? I only found methods from linear algebra that use the original function (which I don't know). Efficiency of the used method doesn't matter in that context, a relatively high accuracy would be important.

Comment: Are the points in `points` sorted in the order of the curve? If yes, you can just sum the distances of every point to the next point.

Comment: yes, they are. That solves it. I knew there had to be an easy solution, thanks